# Ansible hangup over SSH in Gathering Facts

Tags: ansible, ansible-facts

I constantly encounter ansible's hangup over ssh connection. Only restarting the host helps.
But this is a very bad way out.

Hanging occurs at the TASK [Gathering Facts] stage. At the same time, if you interrupt and just go to ssh, it connects without any problems.

Hangup on this command:

```
# ansible-playbook -i hosts docker-server.yml
<HO.ST.I.P> SSH: EXEC ssh -vvv -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o Port=22 -o 'IdentityFile=ot/.ssh/ssh_key"' -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o 'User="root"' -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o ControlPath=/root/.ble/cp/6ae141a49f HO.ST.I.P '/bin/sh -c '"'"'echo ~root && sleep 0'"'"''
```

Ansible's ping is norm.
Ansible version is 2.9.6

Comment: Ansible is just calling out to the regular `ssh` command, so if things are disconnecting it's not really an Ansible problem. Look for logs on the remote host to see whether it was able to establish a connection or not, and see if you can reproduce the problem on the command line by running a similar `ssh` command.

Comment: No errors. "Accepted publickey for root from x.x.x.x port 50459 ssh2: RSA SHA256:XXXXXXXXXXXXXX
Jul 29 14:12:11 sand sshd[217510]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user root(uid=0) by (uid=0)". What could be the problem?